# Implicit Conversion of Class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class temp
{
public:
    temp()
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor created." << std::endl;
    }
    ~temp()
    {

        std::cout << "Deconstructor called." << std::endl;
    }
};

class scopedptr
{
private:
    temp* ptr;
public:
    scopedptr(temp* p)
    {
        ptr = p;
        std::cout << "scoped" << std::endl;
    }
    ~scopedptr()
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        scopedptr a = new temp();
    }
}
```

Most of the code above is not relevant but I wrote it so that there is a background to my question.
My question resides inside the main function, I know the line "scopedptr a = new temp();" will work, my doubt is the what is happening with the object a, is it associated with the class scopedptr or the temp class.
This code does not have many variables but what if there are multiple variables inside both the classes, will object a be able to call methods from class scopedptr or class temp or both.
I'm literally confused, what's happening with the object? which class is its type???

Comment: By writing `scopedptr a = ...;`, you've ensured that `a` always has type `scopedptr`

Comment: `scopedptr a = new temp();` declares `a` to be of type `scopedptr` and initialises it via its constructor with `new temp()`.

Comment: @aman Could you point out where is there the implicit conversion of a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
scopedptr a = new temp();
```

type of `a` is explicitly specified as `scopedptr`. Any usage of `a` must correspond to the type `scopedptr`.

When in doubt, simplify.

```
temp* temp_ptr = new temp();
scopedptr a{temp_ptr};
```

Then, there is less scope for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a `scopedptr` with an owning pointer to a `temp`.

> will object a be able to call methods from class scopedptr or class temp or both

To be able to treat it as a smart pointer, you'd usually add member functions, deferencing the owned pointer:

```
class scopedptr {
public:
    temp* operator->() { return ptr; }
    temp& operator*() { return *ptr; }
};
```

You can now do `a->func();` to call a function in the `temp` object.

Also look into the [Rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for safe handling of the owned pointer.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ye1axebsa)